# How to call delphi's dll in C#?

Tags: c#, delphi

The delphi dll code like this:

```
function TCP_CHECKOUT(const RoomName:string; ClearCard:boolean):Byte
```

when I call it in c#,but always get the error return code.
My c# code like this:

```
[DllImport(@"EHLKEY.dll", EntryPoint = "TCP_CHECKOUT")]
public extern static Byte TCP_CHECKOUT(string RoomName, bool ClearCard);
```

The delphi code user said the return code 255 is not call success.Somebody can help me to solve it?Thanks!

Comment: The Delphi code is wrong. Delphi's `string` is not appropriate for interop, and neither is `boolean`. Contact the author of the DLL and tell them to use appropriate types for the parameters.

Comment: Delphi's calling convention is not MS fastcall. This function can't be called from c#. You'll need to change the Delphi code to allow that.

Comment: @KenWhite  Any other method to avoid this misstake?Can I use c++ or others to call it,then use the middleware in c#.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right.Any other method to solve this problem?

Comment: If you can't change the Delphi code then you may need a delphi wrapper in the middle to act as an adapter. But even that might fail if the memory management is handled wrongly by the DLL. Not enough information here to be sure.

Comment: Sure. Write your own Delphi DLL to act as middleman to correct the errors. Better to just have the author fix the issues rather than inject another layer of cruft, though. You can't just use a different non-Delphi language to fix problems caused by Delphi code that uses wrong types and calling conventions.

Comment: @KenWhite: Yeah, I am so dumb. Deleted comment.